# How to find a modal view id on odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-12

Im new to odoo and I need to change the modal view that shows when you edit a contact and you click the Add button on Contacts & Addresses. I need the view name to add some code with xpath.

How can I find the name or id of that specific view???
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The add button refers to `one2many` field named `child_ids` in `res.partner` model see

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/views/res_partner_views.xml#L238

By clicking on it directs you to the form view so you can create a new record in `res.partner`

so basically the view that you are looking for is `res.partner.form`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your python file with your specific id please attention to this example:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="level_form">
   <field name="name">example form</field>
   <field name="model">levels.from</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form>
         <sheet>
            <group>
               <field name="levelno" />
               <button name="open_conditional_view" string="Classify" 
                    type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </field>
             </group>
         </sheet>
      </form>
    </field>
 </record>
```

you have to define type = object and write the function with the same name of this button and at your model.py file like this:

```
def open_conditional_view(self):
if your condition to set view:
    view_id = self.env.ref('your_module_name.id of your view when condition is true').id
else:
    view_id = self.env.ref('your_module_name.id of your view when condition is false').id
return {
    'name': 'test ',
    'view_mode':'form',
    'res_model':'your model name of view',
    'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
    'target':'new',
    'views':[(view_id,'tree')],
}
```